# SwiftUI Picker issue with Rectangle() instead of Text()

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, picker

I want to use a SwiftUI Picker to select different colors. Instead of using Text() for each item in a picker, I want to use a Rectangle() to visually show the color, but SwiftUI doesn't like it and shows me a bunch of blank spaces. Here are my implementations:

```
struct TeamColorPicker: View {
    @State var teamColor: ColorSquare = ColorSquare(color: .blue)
    var listOfColorsAvailable: [String] = ["Red", "Blue", "Teal", "Green", "Yellow", "Orange"]
        
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Team Color", selection: $teamColor) {
            ForEach(listOfColorsAvailable, id: \.self) { colorString in
                let color = Color(colorString)
                ColorSquare(color: color)
                    .tag(color)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
struct ColorSquare: View, Hashable {
    var color: Color
    
    static func == (lhs: ColorSquare, rhs: ColorSquare) -> Bool {
        return lhs.color == rhs.color
    }


    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(color)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle().fill(color).aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fill).scaleEffect(0.025)
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any guidance!!

I read somewhere that the Picker expects the `selection` element to conform to `Hashable`, so I made the `ColorSquare` struct for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue might be with using a custom type (ColorSquare) as the selection type for the Picker. The selection type must conform to the Hashable and Equatable protocols. In your case, ColorSquare conforms to Hashable, but you also need to make it conform to Equatable.

Here's the modified ColorSquare struct:

```
struct ColorSquare: View, Hashable, Equatable {
    var color: Color
    
    static func == (lhs: ColorSquare, rhs: ColorSquare) -> Bool {
        return lhs.color == rhs.color
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(color)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle().fill(color).aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fill).scaleEffect(0.025)
    }
}
```

Now, try updating your TeamColorPicker as follows:

```
struct TeamColorPicker: View {
    @State private var selectedColor: Color = .blue
    var listOfColorsAvailable: [String] = ["Red", "Blue", "Teal", "Green", "Yellow", "Orange"]
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Team Color", selection: $selectedColor) {
            ForEach(listOfColorsAvailable, id: \.self) { colorString in
                let color = Color(colorString)
                ColorSquare(color: color)
                    .tag(color)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S: I hope that if this is not correct, it at least helps you to find direction, all the best!

Answer (score 0):

Picker has a number of limitations about what it can display.

The following example code shows how to display the `listOfColorsAvailable`
but only with the `.wheel` and `.inline` style picker.

Note the selection `teamColor`, must match the type of the `tag()` of the picker elements.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TeamColorPicker()
    }
}

struct TeamColorPicker: View {
    @State private var teamColor: String = "Blue" // <--- here, same type as tag()

    var listOfColorsAvailable: [String] = ["Red", "Blue", "Teal", "Green", "Yellow", "Orange"]
        
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Team Color", selection: $teamColor) {
            ForEach(listOfColorsAvailable, id: \.self) { colorString in
                ColorSquare(color: asColor(colorString))
                    .tag(colorString) // <--- here, same type as teamColor
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(.wheel) // <--- here, .wheel, .inline
    }
    
    // for testing, can use Assets.xcassets
    func asColor( _ color: String) -> Color {
        switch color {
            case "Red": Color.red
            case "Blue": Color.blue
            case "Teal": Color.teal
            case "Green": Color.green
            case "Yellow": Color.yellow
            case "Orange": Color.orange
            default: Color.black
        }
    }
}

struct ColorSquare: View {
    var color: Color

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle().fill(color).frame(width: 22, height: 22)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, using `Color` directly:

```
struct TeamColorPicker: View {
    @State private var teamColor: Color = Color.blue // <--- here, same type as tag()

    let listOfColorsAvailable: [Color] = [.red, .blue, .teal, .green, .yellow, .orange]
        
    var body: some View {
        teamColor.frame(width: 22, height: 22) // <-- for testing
        Picker("Team Color", selection: $teamColor) {
            ForEach(listOfColorsAvailable, id: \.self) { color in
                ColorSquare(color: color)
                    .tag(color) // <--- here, same type as teamColor
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(.wheel) // <--- here, .wheel, .inline
    }

}

struct ColorSquare: View {
    var color: Color

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle().fill(color).frame(width: 22, height: 22)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use a `Picker` to select a `Color` then it can be done by converting each `Color` to an `Image`. Each image can then be used to create a `Label`.

Like this:

```swift
struct TeamColorPicker: View {
    @State var teamColor: Color = .red
    var listOfColorsAvailable: [String] = ["Red", "Blue", "Teal", "Green", "Yellow", "Orange"]

    private func colorImage(color: Color) -> Image {
        Image(size: CGSize(width: 26, height: 20)) { ctx in // includes trailing padding
            ctx.fill(
                Path(
                    roundedRect: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)),
                    cornerRadius: 3
                ),
                with: .color(color)
            )
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Picker("Team Color", selection: $teamColor) {
            ForEach(listOfColorsAvailable, id: \.self) { colorString in
                let color = Color(colorString)
                Label(
                    title: { Text(colorString) },
                    icon: { colorImage(color: color) }
                )
                .tag(color)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Ps. I used the same code to convert a `String` to a `Color` as you were using, but for this to work, you need to add colors with these exact names to your asset catalog. You could also add images with these exact names to your asset catalog too, then you could use them as label images directly.