# Why does data not populate list inside popover in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, popover, swiftui-picker

### What I'm Looking For

I'm hoping someone can help me understand what's going on and why SwiftUI is behaving the way it is in this scenario.

### What I was trying to do

I was originally trying to create a menu with a picker that has a list of calendars for the user to choose from. What was important to me was showing a colored circle to indicate the color of the calendar along with the title. At the time, I couldn't figure out how to get the icons colored in the picker menu. So, I thought a custom popover with a list would work. This is what led to me discovering this issue.

### Setup

- I have a class that is managing creating or retrieving data for me asynchronously.

  - I'm using that data to populate the list of the picker menu and/or popover list
- I have a `State` property that holds onto the data in the view after being fetched
- That data is fetched inside of a `.task` modifier (also tried `Task` inside `onAppear`)
- Lastly, I have a view that consists of a `VStack` that houses the button triggering the popover as well as a picker to act as the menu. Both are populated with the same data

### Problem

When the picker is commented out, the popover always shows up empty, but it retains a frame. When the picker is uncommented, the data not only shows up in the picker, but it shows up in the popover as well. This is what where I'm really stumped. Why does the list in the popover only populate when the Picker I there as well?

### Things I've Tried

- Putting the popover view into its own file
- Using `onAppear` instead of `.task`
- Using a `VStack` instead of a `List` inside the popover
- Making the results from the fetch sit inside the data manager class as an optional and then resetting any time the data fetch is completed

### Code

Can easily copy and try for yourself

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    let dataManager = DataManager()
    @State private var items: [DataItem] = []
    @State private var popoverIsPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                popoverIsPresented = true
            } label: {
                Text("Choose Item")
            }
            .popover(isPresented: $popoverIsPresented, content: {
                List {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        Text(item.title)
                    }
                }
            })
            
//          List {
//              ForEach(items) { item in
//                  Text(item.title)
//              }
//          }
        }
        .task { items = await dataManager.fetchData() }
    }
}

#Preview {
    TestView()
        .frame(minWidth: 300, minHeight: 300)
}

struct DataItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
}

class DataManager {
    
    func fetchData() async -> [DataItem] {
        Array(repeating: .init(title: "This is an example item"), count: 10)
    }
}
```

1. Run it as is
2. Then try uncommenting the Picker and you should then see the data appear in both views

### Best Guess ‍♂️

- the popover doesn't get updated once the `State` property changes (which would be a bug I think)

### Images

[With Picker commented out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBRyo.png)

[With Picker left in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtrqD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, when you refer to a **picker**, you are actually referring to the `List` in your example, right?

I was able to reproduce the issue by uncommenting the `List`. However, there is then an error in the console:

> ForEach<Array, UUID, Text>: the ID 1582CFA9-24C2-49BE-93DF-1D8B5FB949EA occurs multiple times within the collection, this will give undefined results!

Let's fix this, to make sure it is not the cause of the problem. This means building the dummy array in a different way. For example:

```swift
func fetchData() async -> [DataItem] {
//    Array(repeating: .init(title: "This is an example item"), count: 10)
    var result = [DataItem]()
    for n in 0..<10 {
        result.append(DataItem(title: "This is an example item \(n)"))
    }
    return result
}
```

When the `List` is commented out, the `Popover` stays empty, as you described. My guess is that the `body` of the view is not being refreshed when the array is assigned to the state variable, **because none of the visible content is dependent on the state variable**. This may indeed be a bug, as you were suggesting.

As a workaround, try making the `body` dependent on the state variable in some way. For example, you could show the count of items as a hidden `Text` element behind the `Button`:

```swift
Button {
    popoverIsPresented = true
} label: {
    Text("Choose Item")
}
.background { Text("\(items.count)").hidden() } //  ADDED
.popover(isPresented: $popoverIsPresented) {
    List {
        ForEach(items) { item in
            Text(item.title)
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding your original objectives:

> create a menu with a picker that has a list of calendars
>
> showing a colored circle to indicate the color of the calendar along with the title

The answer to [SwiftUI Picker issue with Rectangle() instead of Text()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77818599/20386264) shows how this can be done using a regular `Picker`. See also [Swift Picker Containing A View Not Showing The Color component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78239569/20386264).

Comment: I should have clarified that I used an array literal in my original code. I used repeating here for brevity without realizing that `Array(repeating:count:)` doesn't new instances for each out, just inits once and reuses that instance.

I think we're on the same page that it might be a bug. I will file a report to Apple.

I think your solution's probably the best for now. Also, I did figure out how to get the icons colored in the picker now. However, I'm still running into issues with the selection—and weird that the initial value can't be nil. Might ask that later. Thanks a lot!