# Swift Picker Containing A View Not Showing The Color component

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, uicolor

So I want to have a dropdown containing different categories and each category should have a color, the string value of the category should be binded to my viewmodel.category.

This is what I have:

View:

```swift
Picker("Category", selection: $viewModel.category) {
    ForEach(Category.allCases, id: \.self) { category in
        CategoryView(category: category)
            .tag(category.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Category View:

```swift
struct CategoryView: View {
    let category: Category

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            
            Text(category.rawValue.capitalized)
            
            Circle()
                .fill(category.color)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .padding(.trailing, 8)
        }
    }
}
```

Category Model:

```swift
enum Category: String, CaseIterable {
    case groceries
    case utilities
    case transportation
    case entertainment
    
    var color: Color {
        switch self {
        case .groceries:
            return Color.blue
        case .utilities:
            return Color.green
        case .transportation:
            return Color.orange
        case .entertainment:
            return Color.purple
        }
    }
}
```

The dropdown shows the categories just fine, but with no circle for color:

[image: Screenshot]

Also, if I put just a categoryview hardcoded in the view, like this:

```swift
CategoryView(category: .entertainment)
```

It shows up fine:

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas?

Comment: Youll need a custom picker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to [SwiftUI Picker issue with Rectangle() instead of Text()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77818599/20386264) shows how this can be done (it was my answer):

- convert each `Color` to an `Image`
- build the `Picker` using `Labels` that in turn are built using the name of the category and the color `Image`.

Actually, it works to build the label using your `CategoryView`, but it is only the text part that gets used, so you might as well use the `Text` directly.

Like this:

```swift
private func colorImage(color: Color) -> Image {
    Image(size: CGSize(width: 26, height: 20)) { ctx in // includes trailing padding
        ctx.fill(
            Path(ellipseIn: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))),
            with: .color(color)
        )
    }
}


var body: some View {
    Form {
        Picker("Category", selection: $viewModel.category) {
            ForEach(Category.allCases, id: \.self) { category in
                Label(
                    title: { Text(category.rawValue.capitalized) },
                    icon: { colorImage(color: category.color) }
                )
                .tag(category.rawValue)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]